# Cannot open source file: '..\..\basic-tutorial-1.c': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have SDK that installed on my computer and I run it with visual studio 2010. it also has directory of examples of codes.
when I launch the code from the original directory, its fine.

but when I copy the entire directory of the examples to

```
C:\....\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects
```

and try to open the .sln from there, I get this error:

```
error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\..\basic-tutorial-1.c': No such file or directory
```

am I doing something wrong here..?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are not copying the entire directory, just the entire directory containing the solution? Because ....\basic-tutorial-1.c is situated in a directory that is parent of a parent of a directory with a solution.